# No suggestions on getByRole, queryByRole, etc

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Suggestions when performing queries such as `getByRole`, `queryByRole`, etc. have been very usefull to understand and write more assertive tests with `testing-library/react`.

```
     TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button"
    
        Here are the accessible roles:
        
          heading:
        
          Name "Testing Library Recipes":
          <h1 />
... // more
```

However, I'm trying to dump these suggestions in a different project and the only thing I'm getting is this message:

```
 TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button"

    There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, then set the `hidden` option to `true`. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole
```

Docs are very shallow about this topic: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-configuration/#throwsuggestions-experimental

Adding the `suggest: true` option won't help.

I'm using the following versions:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
```

The `.test`:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { screen, render, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";

import React from "react";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import FAQ from "../../components/elements/FAQ";

describe('FAQ', () => {
    it('get roles', () => {
        render(<HashRouter>
            <FAQ />
        </HashRouter>)
        screen.getByRole('button', { suggest: true });
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

```
const FAQ = () => {
    return (
        <div style={{ marginTop: "13%" }}>
            <ul id="about-ul">
                <h3 className="mt-4">Envíos</h3>
                <li>
                    //text
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShippingFast} color={"orange"} />{" "}
                    // text
                </li>
                <li>
                    // text
                </li>
                <li>
                    // li text
                </li>
                <h3 className="mt-4">Pagos</h3>
                <p>// pharagraph text </p>
                <li>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaypal} color={"blue"} /> &nbsp;
                    <b>PayPal:</b> // text
                </li>
                <li>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={faMoneyBillWaveAlt}
                        color={"green"}
                    />{" "}
                    &nbsp;
                    <b> // text </b> // text
                </li>
                <li>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExchangeAlt} color={"red"} />{" "}
                    &nbsp;
                    <b>// text</b> Al
                    <em>checkout</em> // text
                </li>
                <h3 className="mt-4">// text</h3>
                <li>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPercentage} color={"red"} />
                    // text
                </li>
                    <h4 className="mt-5">// text</h4>
            </ul>

            <div className="container" id="faq-list-container">
                <ul>
                    <p id="faq-list-el">
                        <b>// text</b>
                    </p>
                    <li>
                        // text
                    </li>
                    <b>
                        <p id="faq-list-el">// text</p>
                    </b>
                    <li>
                        // text
                    </li>
                    <b>
                        <p id="faq-list-el"> // text</p>
                    </b>
                    <li>
                        // text
                    </li>
                    <b>
                        <p id="faq-list-el">
                            // text
                        </p>
                    </b>
                    <li>
                       // text
                    </li>
                    <b>
                        // text
                    </b>
                    <li>
                        // text
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <h5 className="mt-4 mb-3">
                    // text
                </h5>

                <Link to="/" id="back-btn">
                    <Button variant={"primary"}>Regresar</Button> // actual Role of the query
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FAQ;
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the component you're trying to test?

Comment: Is `Button` a custom component or is it imported from a library? However unlikely, it might not be handling accessibility correctly. Can you share that component as well or inform us where it's imported from?

Comment: If you call `screen.debug()` in your test, do you see the expected DOM elements?

Comment: Yeah, button comes from `React-bootstrap`. If I `screen.debug()` I do see the entire component. So that might be? That the `button` from `bootstrap` won't work with the `getByRole` query.

Comment: The button from `react-bootstrap` does work with `getByRole`. The error suggests that you can't find _any_ accessible roles, including the several `heading`s you have in your `FAQ` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is suggesting to try using the `hidden` option, not the `suggest` option, to locate a DOM element that may not be visible and/or accessible to a user.

```
describe('FAQ', () => {
  it('get roles', () => {
    render(
      <HashRouter>
        <FAQ />
      </HashRouter>
    );
    screen.getByRole('button', { hidden: true });
  });
});
```

If this still fails to find/locate an element then I suggest using a `testid` fallback on the element you are trying to target and query by `getByTestId`.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either. I ended up using `getByText`, I believe that `getByTestId` has one of the last priorities according to docs.

Comment: @FerToasted I suspect what you are trying to query is not actually hidden, but just "hard" to select. Yes, using a test id should be the last query used from react-testing-library before falling back to conventional query selectors. Can you update your question with the component code you are trying to test? I assume it is the `FAQ` component?

Comment: Yeah I get you, I'm just not sure why it's "hard" to select a role when this component es just JSX. No states, no api calls, no props. It really makes it kind of frustrating...

Comment: sorry for the late confirmation, you deserve every point you've got Drew. Thanks. Keep working hard ;).

Comment: @FerToasted No worries, always glad to help. Cheers and good luck!